# Formula for determining attributes of character created with reproduction

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores, player-characters

I am trying to find information about D&D's rules regarding ability-scores of a character who is a result of two other characters' reproduction. I haven't been able to find any official information on this subject (nor any unofficial information), but I presume that a child so created could have each ability-score selected in one of these methods:

- Rounded average of two corresponding parents' ability-scores (8 + 19 => 13 or 14)
- Either parent's ability-score, chosen randomly (8 + 19 => 8 or 19)
- Absolute value of one parent's ability-score subtracted from another one's (8 + 19 => 11)
- Just follow the same protocol as used when creating a character

Is there any official material on the preferred method, and, if not, which of the methods I listed are more preferable to use? Please keep in mind that I am looking for something that has at least a passing resemblance to real-world genetics.

I am trying to make a zero-player game that uses the rules of D&D 5E whereby each character has varying ability-scores, acts according to an algorithm, and can die from various causes. And since nobody likes a world where nothing happens, I need to add a mechanic to increase the population. I believe that if said mechanic acts close to real-life reproduction, the game will be more realistic. So what I meant by "preferable" means as close as possible to reality. Of course, I will eschew realism in favor of official formulae if said formulae exist.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to the site! Take the [tour], it's a useful introduction to how things work around here. In particular, your question as currently phrased leaves a lot of room for opinion. "Is there any official material for this" is a reasonable question by itself, but once you start asking for house rules, it's helpful to be specific about what criteria you're using to define "preferable" - otherwise, anyone could answer "this one" and we'd have no way of picking *the best* answer, which is one of our site goals.

Comment: I've put this question on hold, as SirTechSpec explains well. Please do check out the [tour]! Your question of what is more preferable is effectively an opinion poll, and we cannot facilitate questions that just seek out opinion, as the [help/dont-ask] will explain in our *Questions to avoid asking* page. However, we could cover what the rules for offspring are, or whether they do not exist, since that's something we can objectively state. We could also give you what is most preferable *for a specific goal*, based on subjective experience. You're not in trouble, we just need clarification.

Comment: [Related.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/40852/8610)

Comment: @HeyICanChan That does seem very much like what I need. Could somebody please flag this question as a duplicate of that question? It appears I am incapable of doing this myself.

Comment: I'm glad that other question's useful, but that question's for a different game system altogether. Although unlikely, perhaps one day a *5e* supplement *will* address reproduction, and this question can be reopened and answered using those rules. In the meantime, the hold and the pointer to the other question should suffice. In other words, don't worry about it. `:-)`